# Android navigation app change the icon of listed menus

Tags: android, menu, navigation, using, sliding

I have use this code for menu icon but does not displayed in app why?
Please help me to to display icon left side of navigation menu list

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/income"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_income"
            android:title="Income" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/expense"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_expense"
            android:title="Expense" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:title="@string/nav_settings" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: You have to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` if contents of menu have changed, and menu should be redrawn.

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 0):

We have to set icon list as null then only it display the icon in navigation menu list

For that use following this code

navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);